# Get selected value of radio button in Asp.net through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I know it has been asked several times and I found many solutions but no solution worked for me.

I am working on IE

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnView" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbtnView_SelectedIndexChanged"
AutoPostBack="True" TabIndex="7" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Show Pending</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Show Processed</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

here is the button code from where I am calling the function:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" OnClick="btnPrint_Click"
Text="Print" ValidationGroup="validationgroup2" TabIndex="9" OnClientClick="doPrint()" />
```

here is the javascrit function

```
function doPrint() {
    debugger;
    var rad = $('#<%=rbtnView.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var radioValue = $("input[name='YOURVALUEFORTHEGROUP']:checked").val();
```

replace YOURVALUEFORTHEGROUP

Comment: I am using RadioButtonList so that is why I didn't use group name

Comment: mmm when it renders does it render as html input type radio... if so then this is how you do it. If not then apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function works just fine. But you are doing a form post (PostBack) when pressing the `btnPrint` button.

You can use a regular button instead of an asp.net Control. Or if you need a PostBack to execute the `btnPrint_Click` method. But then you can get the value there. It all depends why you need the value client side.

```
<input type="button" value="Get value" onclick="doPrint()" />
```

Or add `return false` to the aspnet button.

```
OnClientClick="doPrint(); return false;"
```

Comment: I have to do it from client side because I am printing gridview data from javascript, and I have to check which one is checked?

Comment: Then as long as you don't need `btnPrint_Click`, use a regular button or add the return false to the OnClientClick.

Comment: ok let suppose I changed button with input. Now how to get value of radiobutton?

Comment: Exactly the same, only `OnClientClick` becomes `click`